# Typescript and sinon to stuib function of jsonwebtoken

Tags: typescript, sinon

I'm trying to mock(using stub) the function verify from the jsonwebtoken library in Typescript, I've installed typescript jsonwebtoken sinon mocha chai and its corresponding types. When I try to stub the function I got an error in the IDE(vscode) => Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type void.

```
const stub = sinon.stub(jwt, "verify");
    stub.returns("valid"); //error
```

Why is this happening? the verify method returns (string | jwt.JwtPayload)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `sinon.stub()` can't match the correct function overload signature automatically when working with TypeScript. You have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to let the TS know which overload signature to match.

E.g.

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import jwt, { Secret } from 'jsonwebtoken';


describe('76392073', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    (sinon.stub(jwt, 'verify') as unknown as sinon.SinonStub<[string, Secret], string>).returns('valid')
    sinon.assert.match(jwt.verify('token', 'shhh'), 'valid')
  })
})
```

Use the type assertions to match this overload signature of `jwt.verify()`:

`@types/jsonwebtoken/index.d.ts`:

```
export function verify(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions): object | string;
```

package versions:

```json
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"@types/sinon": "^7.5.1",
"sinon": "^8.1.1",
"typescript": "^5.0.4",
```